# Compressed file won't unzip in Python

Tags: python, unzip

I want Python to extract a folder and extract it to a random named folder. The "random" part I figured out with no problems. But it will not extract in that folder, I don't know why. Here's my code:

```
    ...

    try:
    print "Trying to save file from " + str(clientaddr)
    rndstr=randomword(20)
    file1 = open("comp" + rndstr +".zip","w")
    file1.write(base64.b64decode(prevdata))
    file1.close()

    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile("comp" + rndstr +".zip")
    zfile.extractall("temp" + rndstr)

    file2 = open("temp" + rndstr + "/ac","r")
    #HERE IT GIVES AN ERROR THAT THE FILE DOESN'T EXIST. IN THE ZIP FILE TO EXTRACT, I AM ABSOLUTELY SURE THAT A FILE NAMED "ac" EXISTS... THE ENTIRE FOLDER REMAINS EMPTY...

    ...
```

When I don't specity the output folder, it extracts...
I have absolutely no clue. I tried almost everything...

EDIT: It occur following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tempxarkbkfwkxxsiolxglok/ac'
```

Comment: Please quote the error traceback in your question. Without that vital information we are left guessing at what the problem might be.

Comment: Does the folder (i.e. `"temp" + rndstr` exist), because you never create it? Also: use the `tempfile` module if you can.

Comment: @dhke Surprisingly it creates the folder, but it remains empty.

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @kjp Version Python 2.7

Comment: Is the version lower than 2.7.4?

Comment: ok that explains it probably. See answer.

Comment: Why not use `zipfile.open("ac", "r")` instead of extracting to an intermediate file?

Comment: Check if your zipfile contains files with absolute paths. In that case they will be extracted outside of your temp directory.

Answer (score 1):

Before Python 2.7.4 - files might get extracted to outside the path specified.

See note in the doc for ZipFile.extractall

https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract

> It is possible that files are created outside of path, e.g. members
> that have absolute filenames starting with "/" or filenames with two
> dots ".."
>
> Changed in version 2.7.4: The zipfile module attempts to prevent that.
> See extract() note.

Answer (score 1):

Well in first part, you are creating a sequential file containing base 64 decoded values from prevdata. As it could (should ?) contain binary data, it would be **much better** to open the file as binary : `open(...,"wb")`. It is harmless on systems that make no difference between text and binary mode like Unix-like ones, and is **necessary** on Windows to avoid tranformation of all `\n` (0x0A) characters in `\r\n` (0x0A, 0x0D) ...

And if Python cannot unzip the file, you should control whether a regular zip program can. If not, that means that the file has been damaged in a previous step. I gave you a possible problem, but as you do not say where prevdata comes, I cannot guess more.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile("comp" + rndstr +".zip")
```

I used

```
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile("comp" + rndstr +".zip","r")
```

And it worked. I think it's something related to python 2.7.3 (Which is under 2.7.4 and have that zip bug which @kjp mencioned)

Answer (score 0):

```
def extracter(file_name, extraction_path):
    """
    Common method to extract tar files parameter includes source directory and destination directory
    :param file_name:
    :param extraction_path:
    """
    if not file_name.exists():
        print("Oops, file doesn't exist!")
    else:
        if tarfile.is_tarfile(file_name):
            tf = tarfile.open(file_name, 'r:*')
            tf.extractall(extraction_path)
            tf.close()
```

Call the method with source and destination method. It handles all type of tar files. no need extra handling of files.